# showing messages using javascript after redirecting to a php page

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, redirect, slim

I'm working on a contact page. It uses Slim 3 framework to redirect. Everything is fine, but I want to add some jQuery code to inform the user whether the email is sent or not.
this is my php code:

```
<?php

require 'vendor/autoload.php';

$app = new Slim\App();

//... slim views codes

$app->get('/', function ($req, $res, $args) {
    return $this->view->render($res, "about.twig");
})->setName('home');


$app->get('/contact', function ($req, $res, $args) {
    return $this->view->render($res, "contact.twig");
})->setName('contact');


$app->post('/contact', function ($request, $response, $args){
    $body = $this->request->getParsedBody();

    $name = $body['name'];
    $email = $body['email'];
    $msg = $body['msg'];

    if(!empty($name) && !empty($email) && !empty($msg) ){
        $cleanName  = filter_var($name,FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
        $cleanEmail = filter_var($email,FILTER_SANITIZE_EMAIL);
        $cleanMsg   = filter_var($msg,FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);

    }else {
        $path = $this->get('router')->pathFor('contact');
        return $response->withRedirect($path);
        // javascript: please fill the fields.
    }

    //sending mail

    ]);

    $result=$mailer->send($message);

    if ($result > 0) {
        // javascript: your email has been sent
        $path = $this->get('router')->pathFor('home');
        return $response->withRedirect($path);

    } else {
        // javascript: error sending mail
        $path = $this->get('router')->pathFor('contact');
        return $response->withRedirect($path);
    }

});

$app->run();
```

As you can see there's basically two page: "contact" and "home".
there's a form in contact page, if form submission is successful and a email is sent, page would be redirected to "home", but if not it would redirect to "contact" again. Now I want to add jQuery code so I can tell the user email has been sent or not.
I've got in my HTML something like this:

```
<div id="feedback" class="success">
  <h3>Success!</h3>
  <p>You're email has been sent.</p>
</div>
```

and in my js file:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    $(".success").click(function() {
        $("#feedback").addClass("dismissed");
    });

});
```

Thanks a lot!

Comment: You can send something through $_GET if the form is successfull and you can make an if statement in the page you get redirected after success where you put your javascript message.

Comment: Why not using `$.ajax()` and check in the contact page whether it was sent or not. if it was sent show message and redirect after some second otherwise show an error message without redirect

Answer (score 0):

```
$message = "Your text";
echo "<script type='text/javascript'>alert('$message');</script>";
```